# sensor fusion on GPS/IMU

Tags: filters, sensor

can anyone gives any link or explained to me on how sensor fusion works on GPS/IMU. as of now, i have gain learn few of the algorithms on Kalman Filter. Currently, im using an arduino Uno as my data acquisition card and MPU6050 as my IMU.

Thank You.

Comment: See the book statistcical sensor fusion Fredrik Gustafsson section 16.2.1 Navigation using GPS and IMU